# pandas crosstab for two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, contingency

I am trying to make a contingency table using `pd.crosstab` from my local dataframe. Imagine we asked 3 people in 2 separate groups the question of whether they like ice cream or not, and here is the result in a dataframe:

```
group1    | group2    
------------------
yes       | no    
no        | maybe 
yes       | no
```

And i would like the contingency table to look like this:

```
      | group1     | group2
----------------------------
yes   | 2          | 0
no    | 1          | 2
maybe | 0          | 1
```

I have played around with pandas and evidently referenced many different resources, including the docs and other posts, but couldn't figure this out. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas has a [crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) function that solve this; first you have to [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) the dataframe:

```
box = df.melt()
pd.crosstab(box.value, box.variable)

variable    group1  group2
value       
maybe          0    1
no             1    2
yes            2    0
```

For performance, it is possible that groupby will be faster, even if it involves a few more steps:

```
box.groupby(["variable", "value"]).size().unstack("variable", fill_value=0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, this helps a lot since I hadn't heard of pd.melt(). I had to ensure that only group1 and group2 columns were in the database, but I easily did this with ```df = data[['group1', 'group2']]```. Thanks!